# How can i render an image came from MongoDB in binary data on React.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload

I built an API that receives post request and save a card of an asset for rent (like Airbnb) , with image.

And in the frontend im working with react

the data saved on MongoDB looks like this: 
_id:objectId:("611f654ed352485804d72e23") 
assetName:"House"
assetDescription:"nice House"
assetAddress:"somewhere"
assetPhone:"052978888"
assetImage:Object
data:Binary('QzpcZmFrZXBhdGhcbWFpbF9CRy5wbmc=',0)
contentType:"C:\fakepath\mail_BG.png"
assetNumber:"430076806"
user_id:objectId("6117a28808fca726801468b3")
__v:0

i want to render multiple cards that the user saved in a page call My Assets ..
i'm getting all the data except the Image ..
i tried almost everything that i could find on the net..
i want to thank everyone in advanced..

adding the codes:

card.jsx

```
import React from 'react';


const Card = ({ card }) => {
  console.log(card.assetImage);
  return (
    <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mt-3">
      <div className="card">

        <img src={card.assetImage} className="p-2" width="100" alt={card.assetName} />
        <div className="card-body">
          <h5 className="card-title">{card.assetName}</h5>
          <p className="card-text">{card.assetDescription}</p>
          <p className="card-text border-top pt-2">
            <b>Tel: </b>
            {card.assetPhone}
            <br />
            {card.assetAddress}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

my-assets.jsx

```
class MyAssets extends Component {

  state = {
    cards: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {

     // sending a GET request via axios to get all the cards

    const { data } = await cardService.getMyAssets();
    if (data.length > 0) this.setState({ cards: data });

  }

  render() {

    const { cards } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <PageHeader>My Assets</PageHeader>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12 mt-4">
            <p>your assets for rent</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          {cards.length > 0 &&
            cards.map(card => <Card card={card} key={card._id} />)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  }
}

export default MyAssets;
```

im adding an image to show you how my react app looks like on the browser : 
[my react app on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAieS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array to a Uint8Array

```
let data = [67, 58, 93, .......]
let uint8 = new Uint8Array(data)
```

Create a File from the Uint8Array.

```
let file = new File([uint8], { type: "image/png" })
```

Create an [Object-URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) for the image file and display it.

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)

return <img src={url}/>
```

Comment: no , that didnt work...  whan i make console.log(url) i got on the console : blob:http://localhost:3000/ea619d5c-6390-4fe3-b0b5-930c6a87c5b6

Comment: no , not at all .. the console is clear of errors